# Permission denied - multiline output to file

Tags: bash, file, shell, heredoc

I try to generate multiline output to file but have Permission denied error. Do you know what is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

something.html << END # Permission denied
<tag></tag>
Some text
more tags
more text 
END
```

Comment: `cat << END > something.html`

Comment: See: [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `... > file` (`... >> file`) - *output* redirections - can be used to output (by appending) to `file`, there is *no* symmetrical `file < ...` construct in POSIX-like shells such as Bash.

Instead, *input* redirections **`<` / `<<` / `<<<` *implicitly* provide input to [*stdin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29)** -  from a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) (`<<`), in this case.

**You need a *command* to read stdin in order to process it**, even if only to send it to a file.
In the latter case, you **combine `cat` with an *output* redirection**: `cat` simply copies stdin input to stdout, which the output redirection then sends to the specified file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > something.html << END # cat with > sends stdin input to a file
<tag></tag>
Some text
more tags
more text 
END
```

---

As for **the symptom you saw**:

```
something.html << END # ...
```

results in an error, because **`something.html` - as the *first* token of the command line, is invariably interpreted as a *command* to execute** - and fails, because there (usually) is no such command:

The **specific error** depends on whether that first token:

- is a *mere filename* (e.g., `something.html` - no path component):

  - `command not found`
- is a *path* (whether relative or absolute; e.g., `./something.html`), and refers to:

  - NO existing item: `No such file or directory`
  - **an existing, non-executable file: `Permission denied`** - meaning: an attempt was made to execute the file, but it isn't executable.
  - an existing directory: `is a directory`